# restsharp and Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am attempting to get an OAuth2 access token from ZOHO using RestSharp code. The Postman simulation works correctly so I know there is something I'm missing in my code.

I always get an "invalid client id" result status.  However in Postman, it works and returns a code when I click the "Get new access token".  I have the same items as in the Postman authorization tab (client_id, client_secret, etc).  In Postman, "Body" is set to "none", and there are no parameters or headers.  The only difference between my code and postman, is that Postman requires the Callback URL.   My code is trying to get the code using "self-client", which bypasses the callback URL.

I have tried several different alternatives to the request call including ParameterType.Body, and ParameterType.GetOrPost.   Is GetOrPost the same as a form?

```
client = New RestClient(ZOHO_API_URL)
request = New RestRequest(TokenUrl, Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") ' also tried: "application/json")
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", 
    ParameterType.GetOrPost)
request.AddParameter("client_id", Client_ID, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
request.AddParameter("client_secret", Client_Secret, 
    ParameterType.GetOrPost)
request.AddParameter("code", Grant_Token, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
response = client.Execute(request)
```

This is the translated Postman code for RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong.  I have tried to view the raw data coming across with Fiddler, but when I do that, Postman indicates a failure.
What code do I need to use to duplicate what Postman is doing?

How do I implement a callback URL if that is also required?

Comment: You may need to activate cookies for the Restsharp Client,  Client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

Answer (score 0):

I quickly checked ZoHo REST API docs and it seems like you should use the Limited Input Device [authentication flow](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/devices/initiation-request.html).

From what I can understand from their help page, you indeed need to do a POST request, but parameters must be specified as query parameters:

```
https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v3/device/code?
client_id=1000.GMB0YULZHJK411248S8I5GZ4CHUEX0&
scope=AaaServer.profile.READ&
grant_type=device_request
```

You will also get better off with JSON set as a default for serialisation and content type just by using `client.UseJson()`.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that Postman is following a redirect from your API endpoint as the functionality is different Postman verses RestSharp (possibly missing a trailing slash or similar).

Try adding

```
client.FollowRedirects = false;
```

to your RestSharp code and analyse the result.

Comment: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1229

For more info on redirect authentication headers in RestSharp